# How to use translate Max(value) and Group By (Value/100) in VB LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm currently stuck trying to translate a "simple" SQL Query to a LINQ Query in VB.

Here's my Table :

```sql
    SELECT ID_FRUIT, MAL, numero 
    FROM MyTable
    where ID_SITE = 9 AND ID_DRT = 106

    ID_FRUIT    MAL     numero
    9           106     100
    9           106     201
    9           106     202
    9           106     203
    9           106     204
    9           106     205
    9           106     206
    9           106     207
    9           106     208
    9           106     209
    9           106     300
    9           106     301
    9           106     302
    9           106     303
    9           106     304
    9           106     305
    9           106     306
    9           106     307
    9           106     200
    9           106     200
    9           106     400
    9           106     401
    9           106     402
    9           106     403
```

My goal is to retrieve the largest number from each hundred (column numero).

Here's my SQL Query :

```sql
SELECT MAX(NUMERO) FROM MyTable WHERE ID_FRUIT = 9 AND MAL = 106 GROUP BY NUMERO/100
```

`ID_FRUIT`, `MAL` and `NUMERO` are `3 integer non nullable`.
Result :

```
    100
    209
    307
    403
```

Now I'm trying to code it in VB, I've got something like that, I think I'm not that far but still not close :

```vb
    Public Function SelectionNumero(ID_FRUIT As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
            Dim MAL As Integer = 106
            Return db.MyTable.Where(Function(s) s.ID_FRUIT = ID_FRUIT).GroupBy(Function(s) s.Numero / 100).Select(Function(s) New With {
                Key .numero = s.Max(Function(m) m.Numero)
                }).ToList()
        End Function
```

I'm currently missing a WHERE clause, and I got the error ID 'BC30311' : Value of type 'List(Of )' cannot be converted to 'List(Of Integer)'.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: Your error is because `SelectionNumero` returns `List(Of Integer)` but your LINQ statement returns `List(Of anonymousType)` based on the `New With { Key .numero }` - instead do `.Select(Function (sg) sg.Max(Function(s) s.Numero))`

Comment: @NetMage I'm using Entity Framework 4.5.2 and I'm Using Microsoft SQL Server. Also thanks for your second comment, it does help me !